# Angular $.formatDate undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an Angular application. I need to parse some data information, and I am using something like this (that used to be working on pure JavaScript function)

```
function returnDate (sel_date){
     var date = $.formatDateTime('MM/dd/yy' ,new Date(sel_date.toString());

     return date;
}
```

This is an example.

When I go to chrome, I can see that `$.formatDateTime` is undefined. Why is that? And how could I overcome usage of $. in angular as from time to time I get 'undefined' message for it?

In my **Index.html** I have:

```
<script src="bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery.formatDateTime/jquery.formatDateTime.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're also importing jQuery itself right?

Comment: Yes, sorry , I haven't copy-pasted all. Yes.

Comment: Hmm ... is it possible that somewhere you're calling `jQuery.noConflict()`?  Does `jQuery.formatDateTime` exist?

Comment: why you are not using the angular filter for date instead?

Comment: @Pointy hmm, I am using `jQuery JavaScript Library v2.0.3` and if I check the jquery file itself I don't see formatDateTime function. Dalorzo hm, how could I use it in this case?

Comment: I suspect that the "formatDateTime" function would come from the "jquery.formatDateTime.js" file you're importing ...

Comment: oh my god :) it seems that the whole folder is missing. so beginner mistake. `Cannot GET /bower_components/jquery.formatDateTime/jquery.formatDateTime.js` I will try to add it and see what it will give me :)

Comment: function dateCtrl($scope, $filter) { 
... 
$filter('date')( 
    '1997-03-01T00:00:00+01:00', 
    'dd/MM/yyyy'); 
}

Comment: @Pointy You were absolutely right. The answer was that I , indeed, didn't have that file. Once I have included it, it started to work. Thank you very much! If you want to make it as an answer, I will mark it as answered. Or maybe to delete this question, as it was a simple one :/

Comment: @Aleks well I was just guessing ... You can answer your own question with something like an admonition that programmers always check the error console :)

Comment: @Pointy the guess was a good one :) thanks, it helped me a lot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error like this shows up, open the source of your html page in a browser, and click on a link

```
<script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
```

And **make sure that the file do exist**. In my case it didn't so the error showed up. Please check your console in a browser (`Net` tab, for example) for any errors. It could save your time.